# How can i bulid this effect to website with no background

Tags: jquery, animation, sass, less

How can I do this :

```
 https://codepen.io/aleksander-koty/pen/KeaGQB
```

But with no background only this star and line

```
org project : 

 https://codepen.io/kenchen/pen/tgBiE
```

Comment: You want a white backgorund ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CSS file you have a tag like this:

[image: CSS file]

There you can change your background color with your color you want:

```
  body {
  background: mix(#3f3251, white, 70%);
}
```

Next time please do your homework. Here's a good tutorial to learn CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/Css/